# How to call a java object function from xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xalan

I am using xalan to make xml/xslt transformation. I can pass a Java object to xslt using

`transformer.setParameter("parameterName",parameterValue);`

Also I can get this value from xslt but I want to call I function from xslt that parameterValue has. Let's assume I innitialize parameterValue

`ParameterValue parameterValue = new ParameterValue("value");`

and ParameterValue has a function called getValue. How can I call this function from xslt.

I tried;

`<xsl:value-of select="$parameterName:getValue()">`

and

`<xsl:value-of select="$parameterName.getValue()">`

but none worked. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation at https://xalan.apache.org/xalan-j/extensions_xsltc.html#java_ext suggests to use:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:pv="http://xml.apache.org/xalan/java/ParameterValue" ...>
  <xsl:value-of select="pv:getValue($parameterName)"/>
```

Make sure, if `ParameterValue` lives in a package (e.g. `example.com.ParameterValue`) that you use that with e.g.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:pv="http://xml.apache.org/xalan/java/example.com.ParameterValue" ...>
  <xsl:value-of select="pv:getValue($parameterName)"/>
```

Comment: thank you very much. that solved :) but can you change the wrong name space use to help other people ```select="mp:getValue($parameterName)"``` should replace with ```select="pm:getValue($parameterName)"``` :)